# Is using a website copier considered active reconnaissance in penetration testing?

Tags: penetration-test, reconnaissance

New to PT and would like to test recon skills.

First, is this considered passive or active recon? Second, would I be jumping into a legal gray area if I used a tool like this on a buiness' website? I'd like to practice but am having trouble determining this.

Answer (score 4):

Generally speaking anything which sends traffic directly to a company's site is considered active rather than passive.

Now most organisations will realise that traffic to a public facing site is fine and not an attack (as long as it's not excessive enough to cause a Denial of Service) but it is a legal grey area as, for example, a spider could hit content that the company considers non-public and that could cause a response from them.

I'd recommend that while you're practicing you stick to one of the many test applications that can be downloaded for example the [OWASP Broken Web Applications Project](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Broken_Web_Applications_Project)